# Debugging Symfony REST API using PhpStorm & Xdebug

Tags: php, symfony, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to setup xdebug for PhpStorm.

Setup is as follows:

- Symfony application is inside Docker container
- I am using it for the REST API calls

What I have tried till now:

- Installed Xdebug - [reference](https://github.com/bytepark/docker-php7-xdebug/blob/master/Dockerfile)

  ```
  RUN pecl install xdebug
  RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
  ```

And run the commands:

```
echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
echo "xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
echo "xdebug.default_enable = 0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
echo "xdebug.remote_enable = 1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
echo "xdebug.remote_autostart = 0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
echo "xdebug.profiler_enable = 0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
echo "xdebug.remote_host = "docker.for.mac.host.internal"" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

Set up PhpStorm like below image(except the port is 8090 as my web application runs on that port. I access the website locally using `localhost:8090/` ):

[image]

Now, when I make API call, nothing happens. It wont stop at breakpoint.

Anyone help me with this please?

PS: I am using `Xdebug Helper` chrome plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to make it work on ***MacBook***. I use `Symfony4` as Rest API which is inside a docker container and Apache server.

1. In `dockerfile`, (make sure to put it almost at the end of the file so that it should not interfere while running `composer` or `cli`)

   ```
   RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
   && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
   && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
   && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
   && echo "xdebug.remote_port = 9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
   && echo "xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
   && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
   && echo "xdebug.remote_host = "host.docker.internal"" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
   ```

   `host.docker.internal` is for Mac and Windows. [More Information](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/87ln1e/good_news_hostdockerinternal_resolves_to_host_on/)
2. in host machine, open `PhpStorm`

   - `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug -> DBGp Proxy`

     IDE Key:  XDEBUG_ECLIPSE
     HOST:     {{host machine IP address}}
     Port:     9000
   - Go to `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers`

     Click `+`, Give it a name, Host is `the address on which your application is running`(in my case it is `localhost`) and Port number for your application(`8090` for my application)

     **I was not able to figure out what should be the path mappings, so I am not covering that part. It does not harm if you do not set it up but slows your application by some seconds.**

     **If you cannot figure out mappings then make sure you uncheck the checkbox `Force break at first line when no mapping specified` which can be found in `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug`**
3. Install chrome plugin [Xdebug Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=de-AT), and follow the instructions provide there.
4. Final step would be enable listener in `PhpStorm`. `Run -> Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections`
5. Enjoy debugging by setting up breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the settings I use in my Docker LAMP stack

https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=0

xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"

xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
```

I use PHP-FPM, so port 9000 was already taken and I changed to 9001. Give it a try, it should work!

Comment: are you using fpm? did you change the port in php  storm too?

Comment: I am using `FROM php:7-apache-jessie`

Comment: what port does phpinfo say xdebug is listening on? have you set the same in the IDE?

Comment: I did not find any info related to that. Could please tell me what is the variable name ? I can see `XDEBUG_CONFIG remote_host={{my_ip_Add}} and PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED=1` and other stuff. And I have set it to 9000 instead of 9001(from your answer)

Comment: @Pradeepb in a php file use `<?php phpinfo();` and access it from your browser. You should see [a section for XDebug](https://blog.pixelingene.com/images/2009-03-22-a-new-post-testing-sl3/image8.png) if it was loaded properly, you may need to restart apache if you hadn't already.

Comment: I did `ob_start();  phpinfo(); $phpinfo = ob_get_contents();` and displayed it in twig template. I cant see xdebug section there.  Not sure how can I do `<?php phpinfo();`  as its Rest API call and I am new to PHP as well :(

Comment: @Pradeepb Put the file into your `/web` directory, for example `/web/phpinfo.php` and access it using `http://localhost:8090/phpinfo.php` Your Apache server configuration should be set to utilize [`DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html) which will allow direct execution of PHP files within that directory.

Comment: I tried that. my Apache configuration messed up and now I have to rebuild my container. Not sure if I will be able to make it work like you said. I had tried `php -i` in the docker container and could not see xdebug section there as well.

Comment: @fyrye I can see the port is 9000.